# Dart concat html

Tags: templates, dart, concatenation

Is there a way to split html files in dart editor?

I try to build a single-page application. I have a lot of reusable templates (moustache4dart) but they are all located in the main html file.

Im searching for a way to write every template in its own file and concat them at build into a single file.

Like grunt-contrib-concat where you define all files that get concatenated to a single one.
Or like include/require in PHP where you can import a file into another files.

Is there a library that does this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't heard of something like that.
You can write an aggregate transformer that does that when you load the page through `pub serve` or build it using `pub build`.

- https://www.dartlang.org/tools/pub/transformers/aggregate.html
- https://www.dartlang.org/tools/pub/transformers/

Comment: sounds promising. i'll give that a try